# Prove a matrix expression leads to an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I want to prove matrix $C$ is invertible:
$$C=I-A^TB(B^TB)^{-1}B^TA(A^TA)^{-1},$$
where $I$ is an identity matrix of appropriate dimensions, and $(A^TA)^{-1}$ and $(B^TB)^{-1}$ imply both $A$ and $B$ have linearly independent columns.

I tried to achieve my goal by proving $\det(C)\neq0$ but got stuck.

Comment: The matrix is not necessairily invertible - consider the case $A=B=I$. Then $C=0$.

Comment: In general if $A$ and $B$ are invertibles you can simplify and you get $C=0$

Comment: Great catches! Many thanks to the two comments above. I didn't realize it was so important that neither of $A$ and $B$ is square in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $\mathrm B \in \mathbb R^{m \times p}$, both having full column rank, we define $\mathrm C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ as follows

$$\mathrm C := \mathrm I_n - \mathrm A^T \mathrm B (\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^T \mathrm A (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1}$$

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\begin{array}{rl} \det (\mathrm C) &= \det (\mathrm I_n - \mathrm A^T \mathrm B (\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^T \mathrm A (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1})\\\\ &= \det (\mathrm I_m - \mathrm A (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1} \mathrm A^T \mathrm B (\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^T)\end{array}$$

Note that

$$\mathrm P_{\mathrm A} := \mathrm A (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A)^{-1} \mathrm A^T \qquad \qquad \qquad \mathrm P_{\mathrm B} := \mathrm B (\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^T$$

are the $m \times m$ projection matrices that project onto the column spaces of $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm B$, respectively.

Hence,

$$\det (\mathrm C) = \det (\mathrm I_m - \mathrm P_{\mathrm A} \mathrm P_{\mathrm B})$$

and, thus, if $\mathrm I_m - \mathrm P_{\mathrm A} \mathrm P_{\mathrm B}$ is invertible, so is $\mathrm C$.

Comment: Thanks! But is proving $I_m-P_AP_B$ trivial? I can only "show" this by drawing from the physical meaning of projections.

Comment: @SibbsGambling I ran out of ideas. Still, my answer provides a *sufficient* condition.

Comment: Right, just lacking the final tiny bit. Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: @SibbsGambling If the column spaces of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal, i.e., $A^T B = O_{n \times p}$, then $P_A P_B = O_m$ and, thus, $C$ is invertible.